# Remind "non" novice users about the functionality of the site

Tags: feature-request, voting, notifications, accepted-answer

Is there some way to *help*, remind or alert users who only generate questions but then don't participate in any way in the derivative actions such as upvote, downvote or accept an answer?

It's understandable new users are not familiar with the mechanism of the site, but someone who has more than five questions asked in a relative period of time clearly already has some knowledge about the type of exchange.

[image: A profile page with 9 questions, each with a score of 0.]

At the moment the only existing action if I'm not wrong is to review the user's profile to see the type of behavior and write or not an answer depending on their activity.

As an example, when making questions subsequent to the first one, next or in addition to the `Review your question` alert could be another one like `Remember reviewing your old posts` with a little explanation.

[image: A box titled "Step 2: Review your question" with the content "Your question is ready to publish! Our automated system checked for ways to improve your question and found none."]

Comment: If all their questions have 0 score then why would they have the rep required to upvote or downvote. Have any of their questions been answered?

Comment: In this case, all of them except one with three closing alerts, one of the question has three answers. But my question is something to apply generally, not to a particular user.

Comment: And why is it important at all that they accept questions? That's something that used to be tracked a long time ago and was removed as it encouraged bad behaviour. I.e. hounding people to accept questions.

Comment: My question is not about "accepting answers", but having any kind of interaction after making a question or posting in any SE site like "upvote, downvote or accept an answer". Asking questions and abandon them in an inactive desert I don't think it's too useful neither for the questioner, nor for the respondent, nor for the general user of the site nor for the site itself.

Comment: So we're back to if they can't upvote or downvote and the existing answers don't help them what are you expecting them to do? They can comment on any answers they get but that's about it really unless **you** comment on the questions and tell them how to improve them.

Comment: Well, where in my question did you read I'm expecting them (the user who make a question) to do something?

Comment: And my response is that **you** should help them if you think there's a problem.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. While I help them "personally", I also suggest to the site my concern to increase a better exchange question/answer/comments/activity in general.

Comment: Meh, we are not writing to help the author - we are trying to help future visitors *other* than the OP. If you think the question is worth answering - by all means, disregard the OP's behaviour and proceed. If the Q&A pair is any good, tou will get a steady vote "income" over time, so there is no need to check for OP activity.

Comment: I see. I think I have a somewhat different view of quality. I understand the base of helping future users, but many of them are fed by current, new, recent and old users. If a detail as trivial as the one exposed in this Q makes any user think that it isn't worth to elaborate an answer, no matter how important it may be, as a specific element I don't think it's something relevance. But if little by little the users begin to consider this type of activity as normal... Well, what is known as an action/reaction chain. I insist, the above is insignificant, but adding insignificance makes a total.

Comment: It is worth noting, though, that your concern is not unsubstantiated. Activity rates are not that high - in no small part due to the lack of education and guidance provided by the site itself (the tour is useless and optional, the rules are mostly buried on meta FAQs and the help center, etc)

Comment: - *Activity rates are not that high* - I have been perceiving this daily for a long time and I see it's getting worse, that's why my Post. More than questions, answers, votes and comments, I believe the essence is the exchange. Hence, I insist that promoting this exchange in a real and quality way would greatly benefit everyone in general and the site in particular.

Comment: @Danielillo "Reminding" someone to do something they have never been inclined to do and that in no way benefits them doesn't seem like it will have any affect at all on their behavior. You can lead a horse to water, but you can't make it drink. If anything, the lack of interaction is probably a good thing that discourages users from answering low-effort questions.